# How To create sections in UITbleViewCell with a single NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

As popular sections in `UITableViewCell` with a single `NSArray`?
I have an array of events, load the data into `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, should I create sections by year event.

 example:


 **section 2012**
 Date: 01/01/2012
 Event: Live Music

 Date: 01/02/2012
 Event: Live Music

 **section 2011**
 Date: 01/01/2011
 Event: Live Music

 Date: 01/02/2011
 Event: Live Music

The cells are already populated, I miss only the division into sections, the sections to create two (max two Years).

Sorry, I'm still a little confused, I can not solve, please help me, when test the year? I'll post my code, thanks a lot

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
              //acquisisco la data dell'evento
        NSString *dataEv = [[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + indexPath.section]DataEvento];


//retrive year ,example 2011, 2012 when test?
NSString *Year = [Utility getPartOfDate:dataEv type:UTLGetYear];
    //set image
    ...
    [cell.contentView addSubview:myImg];

    //set day
    day.text = [Utility getPartOfDate:dataEv type:UTLGetNumberOfDay];;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:day];

    //set dayOfWeek
    ...
    dayOfWeek.text = [Utility getPartOfDate:dataEv type:UTLGetDayOfWeek];;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:dayOfWeek];

    //set month
    month.text = [Utility getPartOfDate:dataEv type:UTLGetTextMonth];;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:month];

    //set title
    ...
    lblTitleEvent.text = [[eventi objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + indexPath.section]Artist];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTitoloEvento];

    //set description event
    lblDescEvento.text = [[eventi objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + indexPath.section]Description];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblDescriptionEvent];


      }else{

    lblTitleEvent = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:5];
    lblTitleEvent.text = [[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + indexPath.section]Artista];

    lblDescEvent = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:6];
    lblDescEvent.text = [[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + indexPath.section]Description];
}

return cell;
```

}

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}


    // Customize the number of rows in the table view.
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
       return [events count];        
    }

    - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {        
            if(section == 0){
                return @"Section 1";
            }
            if(section == 1){
                return @"Section 2";
            }
        }
```

Comment: how about transforming your array in a dictionary with years as keys.... and then the number of keys will be the number of sections in your table and the number of elements for each key  will be the number of rows in each section...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

in the cell.textlabel.text:

```
cell.textlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/n%@/n%@",[array1 ObjectAtIndex:row],......];
```

also you have to set the `HightForRow` to a wider space

and so on

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now, I can not access my project, I feel tonight.
 We update

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will have to find out where in your array one section ends and the other begins. In the event that there are two sections, implment

```
numberOfSectionsInTableView:
```

and return 2 or how many sections you may have.

Then change your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` accordingly. You will have to distinguish by section. The first row of the second section (row 0, section 1) must correspond to the first object in your array that is beyond the last one of the prior section. (or so)

You will have to change `numberOfRowsInSection:` accordingly. In your example it will be called twice. Once for section 0 and once for section 1. You return the number of rows in that very section.

For the header you could implement `titleForHeaderInSection:` which retuns the tilte for each section.

You find the documentation in UITableViewDataSource Protocol Reference, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource

If you want to overcome the poor layout capabilities of section headers, then you can implement the table view controller's `viewForHeaderInSection:` ,which retuns a view to be displayed as header for each section. It is documented in UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:viewForFooterInSection:

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now, I can not access my project, I feel tonight.
 We update